# Asp.Net Core 2.0 User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and _signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) still true

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, claims-based-identity

Recently I starting an Asp.Net Core 2.0 MVC project using 
Individual Authentication. ConfigureServices is as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

For some reason, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and _signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) are still true after sign-out, no matter if I do it like this: `await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();` or by `await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);` and no matter if I close and later re-open app in browser.

I need that always, if anybody go back to index app or close and re-open the app in the browser, system signs-out any previously opened session and force to login.

I tried doing following with not success!

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    var auth = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated; // Still true
    if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) // Still true
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        //HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        //{
        //    User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username") }, ""))
        //};
    }
    else
    {
        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: When you say "after sign-out" do you mean on the same request (like you have a breakpoint and are debugging) or on subsequent requests?  Are the cookies still showing up?

Comment: Signing out merely resets the auth cookie with a past expires, which then causes the browser to remove the cookie. On the following request, the cookie is no longer sent, so the user is no longer "signed in". So there's two parts. First, the browser must remove the cookie and second, there must be another request made by the browser.

Comment: nurdyguy, you're right, I'm debugging and I have a breakpoint and when _signInManager.SignOutAsync(); is executed I noted that _signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) continues true, similar if I stop application debugging make some changes and start debugging again, also it still true. My goal: when some user clicks logout, app redirect to login page and _signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) be false, so I guess it is part of the same request, and on the other hand, if the user closes browser and open it again starting the app, redirect to login again and also, _signInManager.IsSignedIn(User) be false.

Comment: According Chris Pratt this stuff would falls in cookies expiration managing and that could be the cause.

Comment: Did you have a chance to resolve the issue? I'm facing with exactly the same now.

Comment: @user216652, I recommend to follow Chris Pratt comments, however I decided to handle it internally, I run _signInManager.SignOutAsync() and after that, I force to redirect to login. I trust on the fact that cookie is expired and if somebody tries to force the url, the controller will reject because this new request will evaluate to false the IsSignedIn. I hope this help.